# Use Gravatar as fallback image if no local image is not found

Tags: images, avatar, gravatar

I have been trying to use Gravator's Identicon as the fallback image, is there is no image for a given user in a predefined image folder.

consider the following scenario;

User email : asd@asd.com

an image is uploaded to `wp-content/images/users/` with the file name `0eb178cec364c022a189c3814e5f7483.jpg` (*The file name is generated with* `md5("asd@asd.com"."customkey");`)

If an imaage file is available as `wp-content/images/users/0eb178cec364c022a189c3814e5f7483.jpg`, I need to show that image as the users avatar.  If there is no such image, Gravatar will be shown.

So far I have tried using the Gravatar as the background, but there is a broken image icon shown if a custom image is not available.

I am looking for non-plugin solution as all the plugins use default uploads folder and create many thumbnails even for this purpose, which is fully unnecessary. I couldn't find any plugins which tick **all** the boxes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also It is not practical to gave Gravatar loaded custom images for all users as all of them have a company email address, and *not* their personal email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `get_avatar_url` filter (see the arguments passed [here in the source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_data/)) to change the avatar url and then simply use `get_avatar()` with the user email in the theme as you're used to.

```
add_filter('get_avatar_url', 'wpse_avatar_or_gravatar', 10, 3);
function wpse_avatar_or_gravatar($url, $id_or_email, $args) {
    // was id passed via $id_or_email
    if ($id_or_email == intval($id_or_email)) {
        $userdata = get_userdata($id_or_email);
        $email = $userdata->user_email;
    }
    // was email passed via $id_or_email
    else {
        $email = $id_or_email;
    }

    $path = sprintf('%s/images/users/%s.jpg',
                WP_CONTENT_DIR,
                md5($email . "customkey")
            );

        // image exists, return url
        if (file_exists($path)) {
                $url = sprintf('%s/images/users/%s.jpg',
                    WP_CONTENT_URL,
                    md5($email . "customkey")
                );
        }
        else {
                $url = "https://0.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5($email . 'customkey') . "?s=64&d=identicon&f=y&r=g";
        }
        // image does not exist, return default avatar
        return $url;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. I added `global $current_user;` and `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` the get the current user's email address. Also changed to `get_avatar_url` as the above function only gave a text link rather than an image. But when I view the users page, all users have the current user's avatar. How can I display individual avatars separately with the above?

Comment: Yes, I meant to use `get_avatar_url` as well. This happens because yo use `$current_user`. I will update the answer

Comment: The code I have modified is in here> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/551f22507b7edf2be1b70d4c5a9f86c9 I had to edit the core pages to force them to use "email" address rather than user ID when generating md5 hash. Also the images are stored in `/wp-content/images`. Uploads folder is not used.

Comment: **Never** edit core WordPress files (ie those files in /wp-admin/includes/ or /wp-includes/)! I have updated again to use the wp-content constants instead of the upload dir, must have misread that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I reverted the edits in core files. Your function resulted in a broken link when no local file was available. I added an if function to return Gravatar.

Comment: @Sid I was reluctant to approve your edit. By default, WordPress should provide a proper gravatar link. Maybe some other code is messing with this? Nevertheless, if this works now I'm happy for you

Comment: My thoughts exactly! But nah. Nothing I could think of. Tx for the support! :D